# firebase cloud functions hosting for next.js with apollo graphql server

Tags: firebase, graphql, google-cloud-functions, next.js, apollo

I deploy next.js project implements apollo graphql server into *cloud function whithin firebase*.

On localhost it all works properly. I can open graphql playground on [/api/graphql](http:///api/graphql) url and execute queries and retrieve responses.

But when deployed to **firebase** it stops working.

I can reach qraphql playground on https://test-course-d1335.web.app/api/graphql

but it displays message:

> Server cannot be reached

and no query can be executed.

*Cloud function returns "timeout" in firebase console logs.*

**code listings:**

```
https://sealmu.gitbook.io/code-example-firebase-cloud-functions-next-js-apol/
```

**on firebase screenshot:**
[image]

**localhost screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Could you share the code you are using? Also, since you mentioned that the function is timing out, are using the default timeout of GCF? If you want to extend it, you can follow these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout), which might fix the issue.

Comment: sure, it's the code: https://github.com/sealmu/test-course/tree/test

Comment: and yep, it's standard 60s timeout, but I unfortunately I don't get too much in console logs, only: 'status timeout' message

Comment: other functions (without graphql-apollo request) still working correctly: https://test-course-d1335.web.app/api/hello

Comment: So if you were to increase the timeout when deploying with `gcloud functions deploy functionName --timeout=540` (which is the maximum), the issue still occurs?

Comment: sure it is. now while investigating the issue I see the source of the problem is in apollo server when running on cloud functions

Comment: and can you share what the issue is? Have you found a solution to it?

Comment: I suppose the problem is somehow in the way how Apollo server treats request body. It looks like it tries to parse the body and in the way it already done before waits forever and it causes timeout error. 
Opened another question regarding this issue:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115626/preventing-request-body-parsing-in-firebase-cloud-function-or-in-apollo-server-c

Comment: After discovering the issue, I have some conclusions described in the following new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414765/apollo-server-micro-body-stream-reading-issue-when-using-on-firebase-cloud-fun