# apollo-server-micro body stream reading issue ( when using on firebase cloud functions )

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, apollo, apollo-server

apollo-server-micro package tries to receive request body stream that already received before(in some scenarios) and hangs on forever cause never receives events of stream(it already fully obtained)

I gone step by step through all the flow to discover the issue.
In brief the issue pops up when request stream that passed to Apollo already read before. It means we already had used for example: body.on('data', onData) &  body.on('end', onEnd) or it was executed by another chain in the flow(express server, next.js server, firebase cloud function).

And if it was before what is going in apollo-server-micro code is that it tries to do it again, but it will never occur and we will fail on timeout or never get the response, because: body.on('data', or body.on('end' will never be called again(the stream already parsed before fully, these event will not happen).

So I think some way is needed to treat this situation and to give Apollo option to work with body stream already received. May be we need some way to say Apollo to not try to receive body stream if it already exists and just deliver it already prepared(buffer) by some property. So we don't need to do it if I already can provide it to the Apollo.

I found some hack I can do, but by far it needed to be done in more proper way.
Apollo uses json function from micro package (https://github.com/vercel/micro) to get the body stream. if I change this line there:

```
const body = rawBodyMap.get(req);
```

to something like:

```
const body = rawBodyMap.get(req) || req.rawBody;
```

I have **rawBody** because I use firebase cloud function and when it receives body stream it saves received stream buffer in rawBody property of request (and it's exactly what json function of micro tries to achieve).

---

***full flow:***

**src/ApolloServer.ts    ( from apollo-server-micro package )**

```
import { graphqlMicro } from './microApollo';
 const graphqlHandler = graphqlMicro(() => {
        return this.createGraphQLServerOptions(req, res);
 });
 const responseData = await graphqlHandler(req, res);
 send(res, 200, responseData);
```

**microApollo.ts**  -  we use here json function from 'micro' passing req as parameter

```
import { send, json, RequestHandler } from 'micro';    ( https://github.com/vercel/micro )
  const graphqlHandler = async (req: MicroRequest, res: ServerResponse) => {
    let query;
    try {
      query =
        req.method === 'POST'
          ? req.filePayload || (await json(req))
          : url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    } catch (error) {
      // Do nothing; `query` stays `undefined`
    }
```

**https://github.com/vercel/micro package**

```
const getRawBody = require('raw-body');
exports.json = (req, opts) =>
    exports.text(req, opts).then(body => parseJSON(body));

exports.text = (req, {limit, encoding} = {}) =>
    exports.buffer(req, {limit, encoding}).then(body => body.toString(encoding));

exports.buffer = (req, {limit = '1mb', encoding} = {}) =>
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        const type = req.headers['content-type'] || 'text/plain';
        const length = req.headers['content-length'];
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undefined
        if (encoding === undefined) {
            encoding = contentType.parse(type).parameters.charset;
        }
```

//   my try to hack the behavior

> ```
> const body = rawBodyMap.get(req) || req.rawBody;
> console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", body);
> ```

```
if (body) {
        return body;
    }
    return getRawBody(req, {limit, length, encoding})
        .then(buf => {
            rawBodyMap.set(req, buf);
            return buf;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.type === 'entity.too.large') {
                throw createError(413, `Body exceeded ${limit} limit`, err);
            } else {
                throw createError(400, 'Invalid body', err);
            }
        });
});
```

> if I don't stop by my hack the code from going to receive the body
> stream it calls to : getRawBody from 'raw-body' package;

**raw-body package**

```
function getRawBody (stream, options, callback) {
……
  return new Promise(function executor (resolve, reject) {
    readStream(stream, encoding, length, limit, function onRead (err, buf) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(buf)
    })
  })
}
function readStream (stream, encoding, length, limit, callback) {
…….
  // attach listeners
// these callbacks never called because body request stream already received before
  stream.on('aborted', onAborted)
  stream.on('close', cleanup)
  stream.on('data', onData)
  stream.on('end', onEnd)
  stream.on('error', onEnd)
…….
```

Comment: Pardon, while I certainly appreciate the description of the code and what you're trying to achieve... I'm not sure what the question is? The way you describe the problem it would seem you have already solved it.

Comment: I just patched locally a related library in some way. Change should be done in Apollo I suppose or in related libraries, in the way I can use Apollo server just by passing some prop. Now I don't see an option

Comment: I'm sorry, could you rephrase that? I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: I patched locally a related library of Apollo in node_modules dependencies. But change should be done in Apollo I suppose or in related libraries Apollo uses, in the way I can use Apollo server just by passing some prop(with received buffer, because I don't have a way to prevent cloud function from treating stream and leaving the work for Apollo's turn). Now I don't see an option (what I've done was just for emphasizing the problem in local dev, it can't work for ci\cd e.t.c)

Comment: I've been looking through the documentation for both Apollo and micro and... It's honestly a little weird: Apollo is a server that uses micro's systems to process things, a lot of these things already exist to a degree within node itself (jsonParse for example, micro just simplifies it slightly); however: micro is intended for containerized processes, therefore it doesn't interact well with serverless systems, such as Cloud Functions. I believe your best bet would be to inform the Apollo developers of this [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server), as micro isn't intended for this

Comment: Thank you, again, for clarifying. This didn't fit in the original comment.